# Javascript.Php. Как считать со своего компьютера cookie любого домена через бразуер?

Tags: php, javascript, cookie

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли считать со своего компьютера cookie любого домена через бразуер путем скрипта например на Php или Javascript?

Тоесть в скрипте указывать домен, например yandex.ru и получать список cookie сохраненных на моем компьютере
Спасибо заранее за ответы

Comment: Вам на Тостере уже ответили же

Comment: Нет (и еще 12 символов).

Comment: Зачем это (и ещё 6 символов)?